# Get custom posts by segment of the URL

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

Please give me a suggestion this situation of mine.
I have a custom post type `"house"`.
It comes with 2 custom taxonomies: `"region"` and `"status"`.

I would like to get out all the "house" which are `"for rent"` and are located in `"istanbul"` of `"turkey"`when I type this URL to the browser:

`hostname.com/for-rent/turkey/istanbul`

Thanks

Comment: Do you already have the page ready to display the posts?

Comment: Yes I do. I want to detect the URL segment to modify the query now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewrite rule in your htaccess:

/for-rent/turkey/istanbul

```
RewriteRule ^for-rent/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ yourpage.php?country=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

Than in your yourpage.php:

```
$country = $_REQUEST['country'];
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
```